# Expressions in EJS templates

Tags: javascript, node.js, expression, ejs

Is it possible to use javascript expression inside an ejs template?

Example:

cars.js

```
app.get("/cars", function(req, res) {
    res.render("cars.ejs", {
        cars: cars
    });
});
```

cars.ejs

```
<% cars.forEach(function(car) { %>
   <% var car_price = car.price.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'); %>
<% }) %>
```

How can I do something like this

```
var car_price = car.price.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');
```

Inside the template???

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Do not do it, it's almost impossible to debug if something goes wrong.
There is no stack trace. Keep the logic in the model

Comment: ```aggregations: {
  models: {
    buckets: [
      {
        "agg_top": {
          "hits": {
            "hits": [
              {
                "_type": "cars",
                "_id": "13214AJK21LM",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                  "core": "1.4 MultiJet 140CV 2WD MT",
                  "price": "27290",
                  "description": "White",
                  "model": "871",
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}```

Comment: I'm working with a dataset like this, the only thing I do is a sort of parse to make it more readable.. How would you do it?

Comment: I have done something similar recently and done the calculations in the route before res.render. However, I have done it the way you have described above, it works, but there are many articles out there on why not to do it. Like handlebars, ejs, you will have no stack trace to debug.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use any Javascript expression between `<% %>` inside an _ejs_ template. This is actually what you are doing right now.